# Multiple Ajax calls sometimes fail

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sqlite

I have a PHP script which queries a database and returns a table, depending on the input, e.g.results.php?f=1.

I am trying to call it multiple times from JavaScript:

```
function go(n,divid) {
 document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = "<img src=\"load.gif\">";
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", n, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Call later

```
    go('results.php?print=1&nh=1','d1');
    go('results.php?print=2&nh=1','d2');
    go('results.php?print=3&nh=1','d3');
    go('results.php?print=4&nh=1','d4');
```

The PHP code connects to a SQLite3 database. The problem with the above is that sometimes it works, but sometimes one of the queries fails to be prepared by SQLite3::prepare().

What could be wrong? A sqlite race condition? A javascript issue?
When results.php is called just once, the query always succeeds.

Thanks.

Comment: Well if ___but sometimes one of the queries fails to be prepared by SQLite3::prepare()___ then it might be useful to see the PHP script that is having these problems

Comment: 55 minutes would seem enough to copy/paste some extra code into your question. So VTC as questions seeking debugging help must include......

Comment: I am not a stackoverflow nerd to be standby on any comment, I am very busy. Besides, it does not seem to me that you would actually help.

Comment: Well for reference: PHP tagged questions get picked up within a few minutes, so in future you might want to watch your question for a few minutes to see if anybody thinks a little more info might be useful

Comment: I also notice that even now you have not added the relevant code to your question, any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use xhttp  instead of xmlhttp.

```
function go(n,divid) {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = "<img src=\"load.gif\">";
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
 xhttp.open("GET", n, true);
 xhttp.send();
}
 go('results.php?print=1&nh=1','d1');
```

Comment: `xhttp` and `xmlhttp` are both variables and therefore this is irrelevant. OP could have called it `WoopyDo` if they wanted to as long as they then continued to use that variable name